# Is there a motor or engine or system for a better control of Roles in Android?

Tags: android, system, role

Is there a motor or engine or system for a better control of Roles and permissions in Android?
I already searched no success.
Thank you.

Comment: You may wish to explain, in much greater detail, what "Roles" are, what they have to do with permissions, and what an "engine or system for a better control" of them would mean.

Comment: i mean something like: The logged in user has roles: creator, editor, etc. so he can see the button create, edit, delete, etc.

Comment: a control of actions and components for specific roles.

Comment: another example @Roles("creator","editor") public void create(){---} "the method can only be executed by the roles [creator, editor]"